# Info not been saved to database in WP plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress plugin. I'm trying to add info to the database(mySQL) but it is not been saved. I don't know why, I have code, I think it's right but obviously there's something wrong with it. Thanks for reading!

[image: UI]

[image: Info I typed in "John" not getting saved to DB!?]

---

Here is my code

Interface to add person name

```
function render_add_person {
        if (!current_user_can('fp_control_form')) {
            wp_die(__('Access denied.', fp_person ));
        }
        $uicreate .= "<form id='fp-person-fm'>\n";
        $uicreate .= "<p><input type='text' id='person-nm' name='perosn-nm' value='' /> ";
        $uicreate .= $this->add_wrap(__('Submit Name', fp_person),"<button class='cc-btn one'>", "</button></p>");
        $uicreate .= "</form>\n";


        echo($uicreate);
    }
```

Insert to database Code

```
// Insert to db
    function db_add_person($person) {
        global $wpdb;
        $output = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . fp_person_tbl,
                                array('p_name'  => $input->person
                                ),
                                array('%s')
                                );
        if ($this->return_result($output)){

            $input->id = $wpdb->insert_id;


            $this->ren_person($person);
        }
    }
```

Render person

```
function ren_person($person){
        $output = array(
            'id'            => $person->id,
            'p_name'    => $input->p_name
         );


        $this->render_json($output);
    }
```

Why is this code not working? Sorry for long question!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You might want to 'lint' your code. Whatever file that code is is, find it in your terminal and use ``php -l /path/to/file.php`` to lint it. It will tell you if there are any syntax errors. That's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do this now

Comment: @Cal I have no syntax errors. Can you tell me if my Insert code is correct?

Comment: ''$wpdb->prefix . fp_person_tbl``  This looks wrong. There are no quotes around fp_person_tbl. Not sure how that is working . if it's a variable, it needs a $. If it is a literal, it needs quotes. Other than that, I can't see anything really wrong with it.

Comment: @Cal It's the name of the table in mySQL DB, should I use double quotes or single quotes? Also, thanks for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll move this into an answer.

```
$output = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . fp_person_tbl,
```

This line should be causing you a problem. The table name needs to be in quotes.

```
$output = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'fp_person_tbl',
```

That should work.

To answer your question, it doesn't matter, single or double would work in this situation. I chose single simply because I didn't have to press the SHIFT key to type them. :) There is no advantage of one over the other.

If it's still not working after that, let's revisit it.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Thanks, I only saw this now. I managed to get it working without using any of my code, instead i just done it manually. This should work now, thanks for explaining!